# Ordering multiple HandlerFilterfunction in SpringWebflux

Tags: spring-webflux

If I have multiple HandlerFilterFunctions in my route config, how do I guarantee the order of their execution? In the code below, how does one ensure that FilterA is called before FilterB?

```
public class RouterConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(MyHandler myHandler) {
        return RouterFunctions
                        .route(RequestPredicates.GET("/some/route")
                                .and(RequestPredicates.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), myHandler::getMyResponse)
                        .filter(new FilterA())
                        .filter(new FilterB())
        }
}
```

Comment: They are added in order, as a list

Comment: When I run this, FilterB gets executed before FilterA

Comment: well then they call the filters in the reverse order. If you look into the source code, they are kept in a List<T> so order is preserved